# What screws to use to hang bathroom mirror cabinet?

Tags: screws, drill, cabinets, hanging, mirror

I have bought a bathroom mirror cabinet which has a mirror on the front door. The door has hinges on its left. There are 4 screw holes on the back near the corners. The box did not come with any screws.

What size screws do I buy to hang this and how do I ensure that the cabinet is levelled when I try to hang it? I guess I will have to drill holes that are about the size of the screws and put in some plastic stuff to hold the screws in place as well right?

I really don't know where to start with this.

Comment: depends on what the wall is made out of

Comment: Is the wall drywall?

Comment: yes it is drywall, in UK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Really, any wood-thread screw that penetrates your framing (studs) at least an inch will do fine. Depending on the back panel construction you may want to use countersunk flat-head screws or pan-head screws. (You wouldn't countersink screws in a very thin back panel.)

If you have steel studs you'll need a sheet metal screw, and I'd use a few more (six rather than four, say).

Drill through the back rails if your cabinet has them, otherwise drill fairly near the top and bottom panels. Putting screws toward the vertical center can lead to sagging when the back panel bows. Don't use the pre-drilled holes unless they align over studs or you use hollow-wall anchors designed for the type of load you're installing.

Try to be aware of what plumbing and electrical hardware may be in your walls and avoid damaging it.

Use a bubble level or a tape measure (from the floor, wall, or ceiling) to set it level.

Comment: Note that a tape measure from the floor, wall, or ceiling will only ensure that the medicine cabinet is _equidistant_ from  the thing being measured from, it will not ensure that it is level. i.e. the floor, wall or ceiling could be out of plumb. Of course, if they're far enough out of plumb the now plumb medicine cabinet will make that very obvious... Otherwise, spot on. :)